# How to trigger a function in a flutter app using a nfc tag

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc

I recently bought nfc sticker tags for 6 $ from amazon and was wondering if I can trigger a function within my flutter app when the nfc tag is being scanned. I want it to happen even when the phone is locked. any help preforming such a thing would be much appreciated and if there is any sample materials or any information regarding this(flutter library) please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in your shoes before and came across this Open Source [flutter-nfc-reader](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader) library. I highly recommend taking a look at this library because making an nfc reader & writer from scratch could take a long time. Documentation is well written and it should be easy to follow along.

It basically fulfills all your needs:

- "trigger a function within my flutter app when the nfc tag is being scanned" ✅
- " I want it to happen even when the phone is locked" ✅
- "any sample materials" ✅

There is one more alternative library if you are interested: [nfc_in_flutter](https://github.com/semlette/nfc_in_flutter).

Thanks.

Comment: couple of questions . I came across this and I was wondering to pull of the lock phone function do I have to keep the nfc stream running in the background or do I have to program the nfc tag to launch the app then run the nfc stream to catch the respond ???

Comment: Yes, you have to do both to achieve your desired behavior:

1. "nfc stream running in the background"
2. "program the nfc tag to launch the app"

Comment: For 1, the library will take care of the background process with `NFCService`. For 2, you will typically write the `bundle ID or package name` of your app to the NFC tag. And when the device scans it, it will open the appropriate app.